# How to return objects from multiple entity by joining by using spring data jpa?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities:  EntityA, EntityB and EntityC.
From those entities I need to get value from the Joining Query into a list of objects by using spring data jpa. 
Query is:

```
select x.id,x.formNo,x.name, z.testScore, y.semester 
   from  EntityA as x left join EntityB as z on x.id = z.a_id 
    inner join EntityC as y on x.c_id = y.id where x.id=1
```

The entities are:

EntityA:

```
  @Entity
  public class EntityA {        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;         
    private String name;        
    private String formNo;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)    
    private EntityB b;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EntityC_id")
    private EntityC c;
}
```

EntityB:

```
@Entity
public class EntityB {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;     
private double testScore;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "EntityA_id")
private EntityA a;  
}
```

EntityC:

```
@Entity
public class EntityC {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;     
private String semester;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "c",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<EntityA> a;    
}
```

I have tried like this

```
@Repository
public interface SomeObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Integer>{   
public final static String FIND_WITH_QUERY 
    = "select x.id,x.formNo,x.name, z.testScore, y.semester 
   from  EntityA as x left join EntityB as z on x.id = z.a_id 
    inner join EntityC as y on x.c_id = y.id where x.id=:id";

    @Query(FIND_WITH_QUERY)
    public List<Object> getObjects(@Param("id") String id);
  }
```

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to realize that JPQL is a different language from SQL, and learn it. JPQL never uses table and column names. JPQL joins rely on associations between entities, and not on an `ON` clause.

The query should thus simply be

```
select x.id,x.formNo,x.name, z.testScore, y.semester
from EntityA x 
left join x.b z
inner join x.c y
where x.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

**JPQL** is a way more different language than **SQL**
if You are not familiar with that you can use *raw SQL query*
we call in **Native Query**

**Add** this line to @Query as follows `nativeQuery = true`

```
@Repository
public interface SomeObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Integer>{   
public final static String FIND_WITH_QUERY 
    = "select x.id,x.formNo,x.name, z.testScore, y.semester 
   from  EntityA as x left join EntityB as z on x.id = z.a_id 
    inner join EntityC as y on x.c_id = y.id where x.id=:id";

    @Query(FIND_WITH_QUERY,nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object> getObjects(@Param("id") String id);
  }
```

> This will return Object Array as Object you need to cast it as Array

```
Object[] objArray = (Object[]) result_from_the_repositoryLayer;
```