# Does Spring Data JPA support join result

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Which means I can customize result Object, and mapping it to the join result besides entity classes property

entityA{
    fieldA
    fieldB
}

entityB{
    fieldA
    fieldC
}

Result{
    fieldA
    fieldB
    fieldC
}

@Query(select a.*,b.c from entityA a,entityB b where a.fieldA = b.fieldA)
 Result customizeResult = entityARepository.nativeQuery()

> How to get Result with 3 fields?

Answer (score 0):

If im understand correctly you want to return custom response not your entity object itself. You can use ResponseBody annotation for your controller and Jackson objectMapper for mapping entity object fields. Assuming you have MyEntity as an Entity object something like below code will work for you. You also need to define MyCustomResponse class and define fields you want to show in response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody MyCustomResponse createEntity(@RequestBody String requestBody) {


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyCustomResponse response = new MyCustomResponse()

    MyEntity model = new MyEntity();
    model = mapper.readValue(requestBody, MyEntity.class);

    response.setSomething("");
    response.setAnotherThing("");
    response.setMyEntity(model);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: the mapping should be done from repository and entity, I have update my question, hope it helps

Comment: than this topic might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410779/how-to-return-objects-from-multiple-entity-by-joining-by-using-spring-data-jpa?rq=1